# ERROR aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter to AWS Lambda with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to subscribe a CloudWatchLogs log group to AWS Lambda with Terraform but it's giving me an error.

My code is:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "test_lambdafunction_logfilter" {
  name            = "test_lambdafunction_logfilter"
  role_arn        = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/dx-dev-rol-datadog-log-forwarder-function"
  log_group_name  = "dx-dev-lg-destination-content-full"
  filter_pattern  = "logtype test"
  destination_arn = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:lambda/dx-dev-lmbd-datadog-log-forwarder-function-01"
  distribution    = "Random"
}
```

> Error: Error creating Cloudwatch log subscription filter:
>  InvalidParameterException: PutSubscriptionFilter operation cannot work with destinationArn for vendor iam
>   status code: 400, request id: 19836154-97e4-48f0-89b5-692f44ab1764

Comment: The `distribution` parameter is only meant to be used when sending logs to a Kinesis stream.

Comment: Hello,
I change this parameter but error persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Terraform [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter.html) states that role_arn and distribution parameters should only be used with Kinesis stream destination.
The error message simply states this fact that you cannot use IAM role parameter when the destination is Lambda.

> **role_arn** - (Optional) If you use **Lambda** as a destination, you should **skip this argument** and use aws_lambda_permission resource for granting access from CloudWatch logs to the destination Lambda function.
>
> **distribution** - (Optional) This property is only applicable when the destination is an Amazon Kinesis stream.

Answer (score 0):

Finally insert  and removing the role_arn parameter has worked:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "dx-dev-lg-destination-content-full" {
  name            = "dx-dev-lg-destination-content-full"
  #role_arn        = "arn:aws:iam:eu-central-1:442793498433:role/dx-dev-rol-datadog-log-forwarder-function"
  log_group_name  = "dx-dev-lg-destination-content-full"
  filter_pattern  = ""
  destination_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:442793498433:function:dx-dev-lmbd-datadog-log-forwarder-function-01"
}
```